# Difference between applying thunk middleware in the storeConfigurator vs createAsyncThunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

My question would be if the are any pros and cons for using these two methods.
applyMiddleware(thunk)
and
createAsyncThunk()

Comment: Hard to answer since they fundamentally do completely different things. `applyMiddleware(thunk)` applies the thunk middleware to your redux store when it's created/configured, and `createAsyncThunk()` is used by Redux-toolkit to create asynchronous actions (and assumes you've used default Redux-toolkit store configuration that includes thunks).

Answer (score 2):

`createAsyncThunk` is just a specialized version of a generic thunk that dispatches a `pending` action and a `fulfilled` or `rejected` action. If you do not need those, you can also use a normal thunk.

But even in that case, you do not need to add the `thunk` middleware in Redux Toolkit - since it is already part of `configureStore`. Otherwise, thunks created by `createAsyncThunk` would not work as well.